# Delphi: Delete visual component references from inherited forms

Tags: delphi

When I delete a visual component in a base form, and forget any references in inherited forms, my application only breaks in runtime.

What I normally do is to use a search tool to find references in .DFM, but I'm not completely satisfied with this method.

Do you have any better recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

maybe [Andreas Hausladen's DFMCheck](http://cc.codegear.com/Item/25538) helps?

Uli.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, but have you used 'inherited' in the inherited dfm?

```
inherited Form1: TForm1
  Caption = 'Form1'
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
end
```

If you have 'object' and not 'inherited' you get a lot of problems.

Comment: Yes, I have inherited. I think you can't have visual inheritance with object, can you?

Comment: @Erick: and sometimes due to bugs in certain Delphi versions `inherited` gets converted to `object`